# How to manage the orientations a Uno App supports on at least iOS?

Tags: c#, uno-platform

Normally, the orientations that an iOS supports are either defined by the app's Info.plist file. or the application delegate's `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. However, this doesn't seem to work in that way with Uno. How should this be done instead?

Answer (score 2):

Since the implementation of the `DisplayInformation` class in Uno, the application references its `AutoRotationPreferences` property by default, instead of referencing the Info.plist configuration.

To exclude or include a orientation from the AutoRotation behaviour you can set this in code:

```
using Windows.Graphics.Display;
...
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
```